# Could not find function "mutate"

Tags: r

I'm running into a problem running the following code:

```
brazil <- brazil %>% mutate (
  ID = paste0(country, block, respondentID)
)
```

where I get the error:

> Error in mutate(., ID = paste0(country, block, respondentID), BlockID = paste0(country, : could not find function "mutate"

Even though Tidyverse is installed, checked library, etc. Is there something basic I'm missing?

Comment: Did you `library(dplyr)` ?

Comment: Try: `brazil <- brazil %>% dplyr::mutate (ID = paste0(country, block, respondentID)
 )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As recommended above, I always make the library explicit in the function call, especially when a function name may collide with other libraries, which could be `plyr` (or several other packages) in the case of `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)

brazil <- brazil %>%
  dplyr::mutate(ID = paste0(country, block, respondentID))
```